# How to avoid user to vote up/down after selecting best answer?

Tags: rating

I am using [answers](https://drupal.org/project/answers), [best answer](https://drupal.org/project/best_answer) and [vote up/down](https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module. But, i am not getting how can this be done? Any suggestion.....

Comment: If you want best answer and vote up/down to work together like that, you will either post a feature request in vote up/down issue queue, or write quite a bit of own code.

Comment: I am new for Drupal. So, i don't have more idea about coding. Still doing

Comment: Sorry, but we can't code for you. Or rather we could, but we are here to help fellow Drupallers, not to do for free what they are doing to earn their upkeep.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read `vud.api.php` from Vote Up/Down module, and create own module using it.

Implement `function hook_vud_access($perm, $entity_type, $entity_id, $value, $tag, $account)`. Make it return `NULL` if best answer was not selected, and `FALSE` if it was.